# Language of ambiguous words

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, ambiguity

Consider an ambiguous context-free grammar $G$. Define $A(G)$ the set of ambiguous words, meaning:
$$A(G) = \{u\in L(G) \mid u \text{ has at least two derivation trees for }G\}$$
Can we say something about $A(G)$ in the general case? In particular, is $A(G)$ a context-free language?

Comment: My hunch is no. Suppose you can divide the productions for $G$ into two subsets, not necessarily disjoint, creating $G_1$ and $G_2$, such that both are unambiguous. This isn't possible in general, but it's sufficient that it is sometimes possible. Now $A(G)$ is (a subset of) $G_1\cap G_2$, which is not necessarily CFG. Lots of handwaving there but perhaps it can be cleaned up into something more formal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard example that context-free languages are not closed under intersection can also be used as a counter-example for the language of ambiguous words.

Construct unambiguous grammars for $\{ a^n b^n c^m \mid m,n\ge 1\}$ and  $\{ a^m b^n c^n \mid m,n\ge 1\}$. Take the union of these grammars in the common way. The union language is of course context-free, but the ambiguous strings are in the intersection, which is not context-free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was quite simple :-)
Now the follow-up would be: is it at least context-sensitive?

Comment: It also is the example for which no unambiguous grammar exists, if I am not mistaken, so it was a natural point to start.

Comment: I am quite convinced the language is context-sensitive. A linear-bounded automaton can try to generate *all* derivations for a given string. This is obvious, except when $\varepsilon$-productions are allowed in the context-free grammar. But those can most probably be removed without changing ambiguity. (Waves hands.)

Comment: How would you remove $ε$-productions from $\{S\rightarrow S \mid \varepsilon\}$ without changing ambiguity?

Comment: @Nathaniel Sorry, you are right. What I intended to say is that we can deduce where derivations $A \Rightarrow^* \varepsilon$ are unambigous or not. This knowledge can be built in the linear-bounded automaton, and then $\varepsilon$-productions can be removed marking all impacted rules as ambiguous. (Shrugging face.)